# how to center plot inside ipywidgets Box?

Tags: plotly, ipywidgets

I can't find the way to center the plotly plot inside ipywidgets Box, could you help me please?

```
from ipywidgets import Box, widgets, Layout
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=[go.Heatmap(z=[1,2,3], zsmooth=False, showscale=False)], layout=go.Layout(width=500, height=500))
Box([fig],layout=Layout())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from ipywidgets import Box, widgets, Layout, VBox
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=[go.Heatmap(z=[1,2,3], zsmooth=False, showscale=False)], layout=go.Layout(width=500, height=500))
VBox([fig],layout=Layout(align_items="center"))
```

https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html for more about layout and styling. Somehow center for `Box` doesn't work with `align_items`. but a `VBox` or `HBox` should serve the same purpose.